# showing MongoDB document value to EJS in a loop

Tags: node.js, mongodb, loops, view, ejs

I'm working on a node project. And node is very new to me so sorry if I ask a lot of stupid questions.

I'm trying to show all of my topics on my index.ejs. The root file already shows them in the console log but I can't seem to get them to show in the view.

The view already loops and knows that there are 2 topics, but the content is empty.
[image: What shows on my page]

This is my code from the routes/index.js

```
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {

  Topic.find({}).exec(function(err, topic)
  {
    if(err){

      console.log('There ware no topics');
      return next(err)
    }
    else
  {
    console.log('Whoop whoop there are some topics');


    res.render('index', { topic: topic } );

    console.log("Logging data: " + topic);
    console.log("Loggin data title out db: " + topic.topicTitle);
    console.log("Loggin data desc out db: " + topic.topicDescription);
    console.log("Loggin data date out db: " + topic.topicDateCreated);
  }
  });

});


module.exports = router;
```

And here is how I try to show it in my views/index.ejs

```
     <ul>
       <% for(var i = 0; i < topic.length; i++) {%>
          <li>
            <div class="post animated fadeInLeft">
               <div class="wrap-ut pull-left">
                   <div class="userinfo pull-left">
                      <div class="avatar">
                         <img src="images/avatar.jpg" alt="default avatar" />
                         <p class="moderator"> <%= topic.fbUsername %> </p>
                      </div>
                   </div>
               <div class="posttext pull-left">
                   <h2 class="topictitle"><a href="/topicdetail/{topic_id}" <%= topic.topicTitle %>  </a></h2>
           </div>
        <div class="clearfix"></div>
     </div>
     <div class="clearfix"></div>
  </div>
  </li>
  <% } %>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

The `topic` variable is an array, so you need to pass the index in order to get the proper Topic document. For instance:

```
<%= topic[i].fbUsername %>
```

Your view should look like:

```
     <ul>
       <% for(var i = 0; i < topic.length; i++) {%>
          <li>
            <div class="post animated fadeInLeft">
               <div class="wrap-ut pull-left">
                   <div class="userinfo pull-left">
                      <div class="avatar">
                         <img src="images/avatar.jpg" alt="default avatar" />
                         <p class="moderator"> <%= topic[i].fbUsername %> </p>
                      </div>
                   </div>
               <div class="posttext pull-left">
                   <h2 class="topictitle"><a href="/topicdetail/{topic_id}"> <%= topic[i].topicTitle %>  </a></h2>
           </div>
        <div class="clearfix"></div>
     </div>
     <div class="clearfix"></div>
  </div>
  </li>
  <% } %>
</ul>
```

**UPDATE**

You also forgot to close the  tag here:

```
--------------------------------------------------------↴
<h2 class="topictitle"><a href="/topicdetail/{topic_id}" <%= topic[i].topicTitle %>  </a></h2>
```

Closing the tag, I was able to see the titles:

```
<h2 class="topictitle"><a href="/topicdetail/{topic_id}"> <%= topic[i].topicTitle %>  </a></h2>
```

Comment: That actually makes a lot of sence !! thank you.
But sadly it still doesn't show anything

Comment: Wow, I had to read it like 5 times before I saw what was missing, indeed the title is showing now !! Now I only need to figure out how to show the username

Comment: It seems that my college does see the usernames. So that seems to be working too but not on my pc :/ 
Thank you for your help

Comment: No problem, sorry I actually made a mistake on my last comment, it was the `<h2>` tag, not the `<a>` that need closing. Anyway, the username should be displaying, unless the field is empty in the database or the field name is wrong, would need more details to debug though.

Comment: Yes I found it ^^.
Well on the pc of my college the username shows. but on mine it doesn't. But when I run the app on my pc I also get errors that she doesn't.
Like when I try to make a topic, make a user, login ... And I've tried running it on my mac to but there it won't even run.